# Remote desktop to a VM on a machine with a single IP

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have a debian dedicated server with a VirtualBox VM with Windows 7 running on it.
I only have 1 IP address.
I want to connect to the VM using remote desktop and I'd prefer to not use VRDP.
I figured some sort of port forwarding on the dedicated server might do the job but I have been unable to find how.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great article about networking in [Virtual Box](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1). Since you are saying that you only have one IP address that you want facing out of your physical then you need to setup Port-Forwarding with [NAT Networking](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1#NAT-PF).